# Vite for Local NPM Link Development

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, vite

I am using Vite to bundle a Vanilla TS npm module. When developing locally, I link this module from another (angular) project through `npm link` while running `vite build --watch`. However, performing a full build takes ~10s.

Is there a way to build in a less-optimized and faster manner for this local development scenario? I'm assuming that's what `vite` does, but I have no need for the server and whatnot.